# Pass properties to a Blazor Component

Tags: c, blazor, blazor-server-side

When i learn about components in Reactjs, I can try something like this

`<Component {...properties} />`  
Now, I learn Blazor. How can I pass properties to some component??

Answer (score 2):

You use `[Parameter]` within the component definition. For example, if you have a Blazor component like this

```razor
// BlazorComponent.razor
<div class="@Class">
  @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter] public string Class { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set;}
}
```

You can consume that like this

```razor
<BlazorComponent Class="some-class">
  <p>Some Content</p>
</BlazorComponent>
```

Which will generate html like

```html
<div class="some-class">
  <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible and exactly how Blazor components have been designed. A quick search of the interwebs has found the following useful documentation and articles;

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#parameters
- https://blazor-tutorial.net/component-parameters
- https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-component-parameters/
- https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

Comment: Consider providing an extract version from those links instead of linking websites, nonetheless, they're relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry, i know about this
but what i want is: When in blazor
<ParentComponent Title="abc" Description="def" /> 
and in ParentComponent.razor  i have something like this  <div {...properties}/> with properties include Title and Description. 
In js, I can do it easily but in Blazor I dont know how

Comment: See answer from @Douglas-Riddle for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what is the purpose of the parameter you are passing i.e a style specific parameter, then you can just use parameters i.e.

calling the component

```
<MyComponent Style="border:0;" />
```

component code:

```
<input type="submit" style="@Style" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Style { get; set; }
}
```

However if the number of atributes you are passing is unknown then you can use an [Input Attributes Dictionary](https://itnext.io/blazor-component-attributes-b70e65fada52).